# VBA to use individual row from a multi row Range

Tags: vba

Assuming I am creating a temporary range variable as follows

```
With wsProj
    Set projStartCell = .Range("D8")
    Set startCell = .Columns(StartCellSearchColumn).Find(What:=TargetText, LookIn:=xlValues, _
                     LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False)
    
    Set tempRangeEnd = projStartCell.End(xlToRight).Offset(1, 0)
    Set tempRange = .Range(startCell, tempRangeEnd)        
    
    ' insert two news rows and ensure they have no fill
    tempRange.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Set insertedRange = tempRange.Offset(-2, 0)
    Call ClearRangeOfFill(insertedRange)
```

So now I have the correct range that I want and I need to format each of the two rows in that range individually, as they have different formats.

Can you format each row individually? i.e. insertedRange.Row(1) for the first row of the range(yeah, but that doesnt work obviously)
Or do I have to create a temporary range for each row and then format it and do it again for the next row?

Comment: `insertedRange.Rows(1)`, not `insertedRange.Row(1)`

Comment: That gives me the whole row, so if the inserted range is: $A$8:$S$9, I want $A8:$S8 only

Comment: I am afraid it doesn't. The above suggestion is correct. Why don't you try `Debug.Print insertedRange.rows(1).Address`. What does it return in Immediate Window? If it returns the whole row, this only means that `insertedRange` was wrongly `Set`. Then, try `Debug.Print insertedRange.Address`.

Comment: insertedRange gives the proper range and using insertedRange.Rows(1).Address does give the correct range. Post it as the answer and I will accept it

Comment: @Chronocidal suggested the correct answer. I only tried explaining why it is correct and how to check that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Range.Row` is a [`Long` Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Range.Row), which provides the first row of the specified Range, and does not accept arguments.  Example:

```
MsgBox insertedRange.Row 'What row does the insertedRange start on?
```

`Range.Rows` is a [`Range` Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Range.Rows), which provides a Object representing the specified Rows of the Range, and accepts either a numerical argument for a single row, or a text argument for multiple rows.  Example:

```
insertedRange.Rows(1).Interior.ColorIndex = 3 'Make the first row Red
insertedRange.Rows("3:5").Interior.ColorIndex = 5 'Make the third, fourth & fifth rows Blue
```

As such, you should be using `insertedRange.Rows(1)`, not `insertedRange.Row(1)`

(It's an easy mistake to make, and the same applies to `Range.Column` and `Range.Columns`.  If you want the full Row/Column, you need to add the [`.EntireRow` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Range.EntireRow) or the `EntireColumn` property)